# car had no power whatsever, tightened battery terminal started, week later no power again tried terminals nothing happened.

Tags: battery

I seem to have a battery,or battery terminal or starter problem? For 3 days my car would have to be jumped, but when i turned it off it would have no power whatsever. I tightened the battery terminals then I had no problems for about 1 week and couple days then it has no power again whatsever. I unconnected the terminals then connected the car started then. I tried to start it the next morning no power again . I had the battery tested it when I jumped it it tested good same with alternator

Comment: what voltage is your battery at before you try to start?
How corroded are your battery posts as well as the cable terminal that connects to your battery?

Comment: And how about the other ends of the battery cables, where they connect to the starter motor and (usually) the engine block?

Comment: What if you disconnect it overnight does it work then?

Answer (score 1):

Check the battery voltage at the posts the next time it seems "dead".

You may have a cracked lead plate link, which wiggling/tightening the terminals may *temporarily* help.  As the battery heats up, the lead expands slightly, closing the gap, and will probably test as "fine".

However, if it cools off or the crack separates due to mechanical vibration, the battery will once again appear totally dead.

The only solution for this scenario is to replace the battery.

I would first, however, do as David suggested in the comments.  Check the battery cables at BOTH ends to make certain you don't have a loose/corroded ground or B+ lead to the starter.  However, if you measure the battery voltage at the POST TIPS, and it is less than 10V, you have a failed battery.  If the battery voltage at the posts is 12.5 volts or more, then I would check the voltage from the other ends of the cables, specifically the large B+ cable ends against bare chassis metal.  If there is little or no voltage reading, suspect the cables and/or where they connect to the vehicle.

Answer (score 1):

Don't just tighten the terminal cables, take them off (at both ends of each cable) and clean the contact surfaces; and check the ground contact. Simple things first.

Answer (score 0):

check alternator fuse and the fuseable link usually found where the wire connects to the terminal at the fuse block.

Answer (score 0):

Completely remove the terminals, clean them and the battery and reinstall.

Check your grounds, make sure they have good contact. Electrical grease helps with corrosion.

Take your car to autozone and have your battery and alternator tested. Not sure if you can remove it and take it in.

IF your alternator, battery and connections are good, something is draining your battery. Which will kill your battery and alternator over time.

I highly suggest having your battery and alternator tested, even if you figure out the problem.